# Hello. How to open URLs step by step form exel or csv and make an action in this links. And how to save session in chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver

So, I have a website and need to log in to this site, open links from the excel or CSV file(these links from the website), and make an action. Could you help me? Please

It works when I open links from `driver.get('link')`
The code is working :

```
import pathlib, pickle
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
import undetected_chromedriver as chromedriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = str(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.absolute()) + 'chromedriver.exe')

driver.get('https://..')
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

cookies = pickle.load(open("webauto\cookies.pkl1", "rb"))
for cookie in cookies:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
driver.get('https://...')

time.sleep(30)
```

But If I want to open links from csv file in the cycle it doesn't to work.

The code isn't working example:

```
import pathlib, pickle
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
import undetected_chromedriver as chromedriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import csv

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = str(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.absolute()) + 'chromedriver.exe')

driver.get('https://../')
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

cookies = pickle.load(open("webauto\cookies.pkl1", "rb"))
for cookie in cookies:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
    with open('webauto\Prjct.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)


    for line in csv_reader:
       # print(line)
       driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
       chrome_options = Options()
       chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
       driver.get(line[0])

time.sleep(30)
```

But it isn's work. Sorry for my shitcode. I just a want automate my action in differnet site.

```
Errors:
PS C:\Users\пользователь\Desktop\py\strt> & C:/Python310/python.exe c:/Users/пользователь/Desktop/py/strt/webauto/djinivana.py
c:\Users\пользователь\Desktop\py\strt\webauto\djinivana.py:9: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = str(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.absolute()) + 'chromedriver.exe')

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:59150/devtools/browser/78603287-0828-48b9-87d9-2720e64541a7
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\пользователь\Desktop\py\strt\webauto\djinivana.py", line 22, in <module>
    for line in csv_reader:
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what is not working with the code? Does the code generate errors or is it not producing the expected results?

Comment: ".for line in csv_reader:
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file."                                                                         I just can't add cookies when I open the link from csv file. It works when I open the link from driver.get('link')

Comment: I've changed my code and problem's description